# How do you make an object/tool appear under Plone on the left navigation frame in the ZMI?

Tags: plone, zope

I would like my object to show up under the Plone site on the left navigation frame in the ZMI. Could not find an obvious way to do this. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your object needs to be folderish to appear on the left frame.

Try adding `isPrincipiaFolderish = True` as a class variable.